# SaveChanges not working when context being added in another class file in C#, EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I am calling a function from my controller.

```
biz.AddActivityLog(Param1, Param2);
```

This function is inside another class file.

Inside that function I am creating a new object with the help of the parameters I received from the function.

Then I am adding my newly created object to context.

```
context.MyObject.Add(Obj);
```

But I am not using `context.SaveChanges();`here.

I perform SaveChanges inside my controller only.

But the Object I added to the Context inside the function is not getting saved.

When I tried the same code without using the function - (created my new object inside my controller itself) its getting saved. Why cannot I just add it to the context on another class and perform Savechanges from my controller?

Please help.

Comment: Do you pass the context object from the class to the Controller? Some more code would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you add the object into the context, its changes gets tracked by the context object. If you never execute the SaveChanges method, those changes get lost at the point, where the context object gets destroyed.

When creating a new context in the controller, a fresh instance gets created without any changed data in it. (Its not implemented as a singleton)

You either have to pass the context to the Controller, or safe the context inside the class where you change it.
But passing the context to the Controller is a really bad practice, since it violates the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) because it mixes mvc code with ef code. If you later decide to switch to another persistence framework you have to alter every controller that used your class.